# why does my button look different in firefox than chrome/safari?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

My button looks normal in firefox but in chrome (and safari) it looks thin.

Any suggestions would be great.

[image: button comparison w/ firefox / chrome]

Comment: you could also use techniques discribed in articles similar to :http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/ to design and implement cross-browser stylled buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML/CSS only tells the browser what it needs to display in a certain place on the page.  It is up to the browsers to display an appropriate graphic in the correct location.  What that graphic is like is down to the specific browser implementation for default widgets.

If you need it to look the same cross browser and cross operating system then you need to consider using css/images to create custom buttons etc, which essentially override the default browser implementations.

You can set a `height` css property to make sure both buttons are the same height, and set an appropriate `width` too.  Be careful with font sizes though that the size of the button doesn't end up too small that your text is no longer visible on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Well they are different browsers, which means they use a different set of 'widgets', this includes buttons and more, thats the same with operating systems. Hope this helped :)